# How to handle focus when ListView is empty

Tags: android, listview, focus, accessibility

## Context

I'm developping an app that has to be fully accessible, for that I need to specify the focus order of the different views of my layout.

My layout looks like this (numbers define the focus order and *3* is the `ListView` and others are common views):

[image: My Layout]

The relevant parts of the XML (considering I used `nextFocusDown` and not `nextFocusForward` on purpose to fit my needs):

```xml
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_1" 
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/view_2" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_2" 
    android:nextFocusDown="@android:id/list" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/view_4" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_4" 
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/view_1" />
```

This works well when the ListView is filled with items, the focus behaves as intended. 1 ⇒ 2 ⇒ 3 (item by item) ⇒ 4 ⇒ 1 ... and so on.

## Problem

Now when my `ListView` is empty the Android focus manager seems to be stuck at the 2nd view. When the focus reach the item *2* the focus is not given to the `ListView` even less to the 4th view. Because when my list contains no item, I'd like the focus to go from *2* to *4* directly.

## Question

Am I missing something or could something else in my code produce this strange behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set focus programetically like below

```
if(yourListViewAdapter.getCount() <= 0) {
     view_2.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.view_4);
}
```

Comment: I thought about this way to go, but I have a few differences (that are too complex to explain here) that makes this hard to achieve. If that's the only way, will still try. Thanks, will accept because it answers the question